# Is unconditionally creating a pointer to the last element of a vector legal?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, undefined-behavior, pointer-arithmetic

I have the following C++ code:

```
void bar(int&);
void baz();

void foo(std::vector<int>& v) {
    int* pointer_to_last = v.data() + (v.size() - 1);
    if (v.size() > 0 && *pointer_to_last == 42) {
        bar(*pointer_to_last);
    } else {
        baz();
    }
}
```

I'm unconditionally creating a pointer to the last element of a vector, but I'm only dereferencing the pointer if the vector is not empty. Is this legal according to the standard or does the code above contain undefined behaviour?

If the above program is legal, is the following program legal as well?

```
void bar(int&);
void baz();

void foo(std::vector<int>& v) {
    int& reference_to_last = v.back();
    if (v.size() > 0 && reference_to_last == 42) {
        bar(reference_to_last);
    } else {
        baz();
    }
}
```

The [reference for `std::vector::back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back) says

> Calling back on an empty container causes undefined behavior.

So I'm assuming this program is not legal. Are there any compiler flags for GCC or Clang or any static analyzers that give me a warning for the code above?

Comment: There's a much better way to solve your problem, and get rid of the ambiguity: Don't define the variable at all! Use the data in the vector directly instead: `if (!v.empty() && v.back() == 42) { bar(v.back()); }`

Comment: won't ```v.size()-1``` overflow with empty vector? Anyway, on empty vector, I think that we have few guarantees about ```v.data()``` and I'll be on @HolyBlackCat opinion.

Comment: @Oersted It will, but there is no problem with the overflow itself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but then I have to call `v.back()` multiple times. Won't this be slower if this code is inside a critical path of my program or am I guaranteed that the compiler does common subexpression elimination here?

Comment: As for detecting invalid uses like this, you need a proper static analyzer tool. The compiler doesn't do that kind of analysis and can't know if a vector is empty or not inside a function.

Comment: @eyelash `back()` is just indexing into an array. It doesn't cost a nanosecond more than accessing through a pointer.

Comment: I suggest try it, build with optimizations, and look at the generated assembly code... I'll bet you won't see any difference! Besides, if there were any difference, it would be so small that it would be practically impossible to measure it. Perhaps if you're doing millions of these in a very tight loop over a very short period of time (few seconds). But then you would probably have parallelized it already, making the issue moot.

Comment: @molbdnilo `back()` might be a function call into the standard library unless a compiler can guarantee that the call will be inlined.

Comment: @eyelash It will be inlined.

Comment: @Oersted `v.size() - 1` overflows on an empty vector but since `v.size()` is unsigned this is not an error. The error occurs when adding that value to the vector data pointer.

Answer (score 5):

Both are illegal. The former is [rejected by UBSAN](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:13,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:13,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:13,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:13,startLineNumber:7),source:%27%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%0Avoid+foo(std::vector%3Cint%3E%26+v)+%7B%0A++++int*+pointer_to_last+%3D+v.data()+%2B+(v.size()+-+1)%3B%0A++++if+(v.size()+%3E+0+%26%26+*pointer_to_last+%3D%3D+42)+%7B%0A++++++++%0A++++%7D+else+%7B%0A++++++++%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++std::vector%3Cint%3E+v%3B%0A++++foo(v)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.22570909891783,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1600,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors+-Wdeprecated+-fsanitize%3Daddress+-fsanitize%3Dundefined+-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG%27,overrides:!(),paneName:Clang,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:Clang,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:46.40234948604993,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+15.0.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:13,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,paneName:%27Clang+output%27,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Clang+output%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:53.59765051395007,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50.77429090108217,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) (aka `-fsanitize=undefined`) (see [`[expr.add]/4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4))

```
runtime error: applying non-zero offset 18446744073709551612 to null pointer
```

And the latter is [rejected by `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:9,endLineNumber:8,positionColumn:9,positionLineNumber:8,selectionStartColumn:9,selectionStartLineNumber:8,startColumn:9,startLineNumber:8),source:%27%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%0Avoid+foo(std::vector%3Cint%3E%26+v)+%7B%0A++++int%26+reference_to_last+%3D+v.back()%3B%0A++++if+(v.size()+%3E+0+%26%26+reference_to_last+%3D%3D+42)+%7B%0A++++++++%0A++++%7D+else+%7B%0A++++++++%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++std::vector%3Cint%3E+v%3B%0A++++foo(v)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.22570909891783,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1600,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors+-Wdeprecated+-fsanitize%3Daddress+-fsanitize%3Dundefined+-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG%27,overrides:!(),paneName:Clang,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:Clang,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:46.40234948604993,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+15.0.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:13,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,paneName:%27Clang+output%27,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Clang+output%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:53.59765051395007,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50.77429090108217,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4):

```
Error: attempt to access an element in an empty container.
```

> Are there any compiler flags for GCC or Clang

The two above, plus `-fsanitize=address`.

`-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` is libstdc++-specific. If you use Clang with libc++ instead of libstdc++, then use `-D_LIBCPP_ENABLE_DEBUG_MODE`. (It seems to require libc++ 17 or newer, their debug mode was broken for a while. It also seems to lack iterator validation. :c)

Comment: Is it possible to find these errors at compile time instead of at run time?

Comment: @eyelash Most probably no. You could try some static analyzers to see if they catch it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++20 Standard the behavior is undefined (7.6.6 Additive operators)

> (4.1) — If P evaluates to a null pointer value and J evaluates to 0,
> the result is a null pointer value.
>
> (4.2) — Otherwise, if P points to an array element i of an array
> object x with n elements (9.3.4.5),80 the expressions P + J and J + P
> (where J has the value j) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) array
> element i + j of x if 0 ≤ i + j ≤ n and the expression P - J points to
> the (possibly-hypothetical) array element i − j of x if 0 ≤ i − j ≤ n.
>
> **(4.3) — Otherwise, the behavior is undefined**